# KILN 0.4.0 Telegram Bot Configuration

Tags: kiln

**Situation:**

I followed the instructions to configure the Telegram Bot for KILN 0.4.0:

1. Chat with BotFather
2. Create bot e.g. MyTezosMonitor, add "about, pic, etc"
3. Get API token from bot
4. Add token to KILN

Now I can open a chat with @MyTezosMonitor and I am receiving the updates correctly.

**Problem:**

Others entering a chat with the bot (e.g. @MyTezosMonitor) can see the bot but do not receive the messages from KILN.

**Desired behavior:**

I want to give someone else other than ME as the owner of the bot the possibility to receive the messages from KILN.

More precise:
I would like to create a private group where I invite the people who need the maintenance information. Additionally add the bot as an admin in order to only let him post the news.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right now Kiln sends a message to *one* conversation that it finds by looking at your bot's conversation history. This is currently a "minimum viable product" version of the feature. We believe it would be pretty easy to extend this behavior to groups as well. Keep an eye on the release notes!

Comment: So in this case the last active conversation or the first one?

Comment: I described the required behavior in more detail in the question.

Comment: It's the last conversion at the time you configure it. So it doesn't change over time unless you reconfigure.

Comment: Should I open a ticket as a feature request and link this question. I would accept your answer then?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/obsidian.systems/tezos-bake-monitor/issues/4

Comment: This feature will be a part of our next Kiln release